# How to make sure you have valid bytes when loading a Image.memory(bytes)

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, dart, base64

I will try to be brief and to the point and provide examples with minimal code. Please let me know if I need to explain this better or you have any questions!

So I have a method that syncs a sqlite database with data from an api. The image data is base64 encoded so before I store the data into my sqlite database I check to make sure it is base64 format I also decode it:

```
...
for (var item in items) {
    if (item['photo'] != null) {
        if (isBase64(item['photo'])) {
            Uint8List photo = base64Decode(item['photo']);
            batch.insert('items', {
              'sku': sku,
              'name': name,
              'description': description,
              'price': price,
              'type_name': itemType,
              'pictureBlob': photo
            });
            } else {
            batch.insert('items', {
              'sku': sku,
              'name': name,
              'description': description,
              'price': price,
              'type_name': itemType
            });
        }
    } else {
        batch.insert('items', {
              'sku': sku,
              'name': name,
              'description': description,
              'price': price,
              'type_name': itemType
         });
    }
}
...
```

Here is my isBase64 check:

```
static bool isBase64(dynamic value) {
    if (value.runtimeType == String) {
      final RegExp rx = RegExp(
        r'^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)?$',
        multiLine: true,
        unicode: true,
      );
      final bool isBase64Valid = rx.hasMatch(value);
      if (isBase64Valid) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Then When I want to load my images and other data into the UI I use a future builder that queries my sqlite db to get a list of productItems. This is how I am loading the images.

```
...
CircleAvatar(
    radius: 65,
    backgroundImage: productItem.pictureBlob != null
    ? Image.memory(productItem.pictureBlob!).image
    : const AssetImage("assets/default.jpg"))
),
...
```

This code will work when the pictureBlobs from the sqlite db are null (because it will then just display the default image) or when the sqlite db has pictureBlobs that have GOOD data for an image. When I say "GOOD data for an image" I mean bytes that when loaded produce an actual image. Somehow I am getting images that pass the isBase64 check but will fail to load and then throw this error:

```
E/FlutterJNI(10713): Failed to decode image
E/FlutterJNI(10713): android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.
E/FlutterJNI(10713):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.nCreate(Native Method)
E/FlutterJNI(10713):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.access$200(ImageDecoder.java:172)
E/FlutterJNI(10713):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ByteBufferSource.createImageDecoder(ImageDecoder.java:242)
E/FlutterJNI(10713):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmapImpl(ImageDecoder.java:1870)
E/FlutterJNI(10713):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.java:1863)
E/FlutterJNI(10713):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.decodeImage(FlutterJNI.java:514)
```

Is there anyway I can check if the image data is good before I store it into my sqlite db? Or perhaps a way to catch this error on the flutter or native side of android?

If someone could push me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!

Comment: what are the first 8-12 bytes of `productItem.pictureBlob` in HEX?

Comment: here are the first 12 bytes of productItem.pictureBlob [47, 57, 106, 47, 52, 65, 65, 81, 83, 107, 90, 74] so in hex 2F396A2F34414151536B5A4A ?

Comment: so it is not binary image format: it is `/9j/4AAQSkZJ` in ascii - most likely its `base64` data for hex binary `ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46  49`

Comment: So how would I be able to catch this before my code tries to read them as actual images? I do not want to assume that my api will always be passing good data for images.

Comment: simply call `base64Decode` on it and you will have valid data - your api gives you `base64` data - you need to decode it

Comment: I am doing that before I insert it into the sqlite database.. If the item['photo'] is proper base64 encoded format.. Otherwise it will be null and display the default image

Comment: so `isBase64` is not working correctly, why don't you remove it at all?

Comment: To my understanding isBase64 is working correctly

Comment: if it's so, and you already decoded data, it would mean that your server encoded first binary into base64 and then encoded it into base64 again? note that you called base64Decode but still your data is not binary, but base64 format

Comment: Okay so that kind of just blew my mind. Turns out you were right the image was encoded twice lol. I decoded it twice and it ended up actually loading my images. Not sure if this answers my question directly but at least I know whats going on now. Thank you my guy.